# Calculating $k$ algebraically smallest eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a very big matrix assume $1000 \times 1000$. I want to find $k$ of its algebraically smallest eigenvalues where $k$ is $2$ or $3$.

I am using MATLAB to solve this problem.

**My Try:**

1. I try to use power method. I wrote my own code but due to some numerical precision error it is not working.
2. I use MATLAB's in build *eigs* function, but when my eigenvalues are very small (in the order of $10^{-5}$), it started malfunctioning.

Looking forward for any generous suggestion. Also, if you know any open source tested power method MATLAB code, then please let me know about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewkahan/Math128/Projects/m128bfin.pdf) document and [this](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/%7Epolizzi/feast/) one could be of major interest to you.